# How to calculate a point of intersection on the surface of a sphere from a point within the sphere facing out along a given vector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, geometry

Working in Unity

I have a working solution using raycasts and a sphere collider, but would like to understand how to accomplish the same result using maths alone.

Scenario is as such:

a) I have a thoretical sphere

b) I project a line from any point within the sphere along any path/direction (both of which are expressed as a Vector3s)

c) I would like to determine the point (also a Vector3) at which the path intersects with the surface of the sphere, as if detected by a raycast returning point data.

I am familiar with the use of COS and SIN plotting points on a 2D plane, but not in 3 dimensions.

Hopefully my description is clear enough.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Problem statement is not clear. Coud you show an example of 2D analog (if applicable)?

Comment: So picture a circle. Withn the circle plot a single point. Then plot a straight a line originating at that point at any angle until it intersects the edge of the circle. Now extend that 2D analog into a 3rd dimension substituting a circle for a sphere and a 2D plotted line for a 3D plotted line. Does that help?

Comment: I've added a quick diagram by example for explaining the 2D analog. A is the origin and B is the determined point of intersection. https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1I5I5SJ6Q2sJMp2xzXeq7BCL66XJ6-sl-PigvvxbCej0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Will this be of any help? https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/equation-of-a-line-in-3d/amp/ If you have two points (center of the sphere, and the given point) you can calculate the equation of the line. Then, if you have equation and a radius, finding your intersection point should be easy (or at least I remember it this way)

Comment: @user2393467 docs link requires access rights

Answer (score 0):

Let sphere is described by equation (where `cx, cy, cz` is sphere center, `R` is radius)

```
(x-cx)^2+(y-cy)^2+(z-cz)^2 = R^2
```

Point `P0`, direction vector is `dir`, so parameteric ray equation is

```
R = P0 + t * dir
```

or in coordinates

```
x = p0.x + t * dir.x 
y = p0.y + t * dir.y 
z = p0.z + t * dir.z
```

Substitute these expressions into sphere equation, solve resulting quadratic equation for unknown parameter `t`.

```
(p0x+t*dirx-cx)^2+.... = R^2
p0x^2+t^2*dirx^2+cx^2+2*p0x*t*dirx-2*p0x*cx-2*t*dirx*cx +... = R^2

t^2*(dirx^2+diry^2+dirz^2) + 
t*(2*p0x*dirx-2*dirx*cx+2*p0y*diry-2*diry*cy+2*p0z*dirz-2*dirz*cz)  
+ (p0x^2+p0y^2+p0z^2+cx^2+cy^2+cz^2-R^2) = 0
```

This is quadratic equation for unknown t

You might get 0, 1, or 2 solution for cases: ray does not intersect sphere, ray touches sphere, ray (line) intersects sphere in two points. For point `P0` inside sphere one root will be negative, ignore it.

After that put `t` value into coordinate equations and get intersection  point.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to work through an example, although to be honest I'm not entirely sure what each step is giving me. An example would be useful if you are able to provide one. Is 'P0' supposed to represent the point of origin within the sphere? Also what is 't'? Thanks again

Comment: Yes, P0 is point of origin within the sphere. t is unknown parameter, after calculation you can use it to get intersection point coordinates.